The hyperlink of the page number to back referring in the list of Bibliography is false
First a minimal working sample is as follows.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  location = {Place},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  date    = {1769},
}
@book{somebook1889,
    location = {Paris},
    author  = {Name, Given},
    title   = {Some title of this publication},
    date    = {1889},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\huge An Example}
\end{center}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A test}
some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769} and \cite{somebook1889}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



As you see, in the list of Bibliography, the page number to back referring is right, but the hyperlink is false since it links to the page before the main matter. Is there any way to solve the problem?

look into the log: it tells you that the problem is that you have duplicated page numbers, and hyperref doesn't like that.

In my opinion the frontispiece should participate to the page numbering of the front matter.
If you prefer not to, issue \pagenumbering{Alph} at the beginning, so you won't have duplicate page numbers.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{somebook1769,
  location = {Place},
  author  = {Name, Given},
  title   = {Some title of this publication},
  date    = {1769},
}
@book{somebook1889,
    location = {Paris},
    author  = {Name, Given},
    title   = {Some title of this publication},
    date    = {1889},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\huge An Example
\end{center}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A test}
some quote from \cite[1348--1368]{somebook1769} and \cite{somebook1889}

\printbibliography

\end{document}

